# how to redirect to my error view in my try catch?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, try-catch

i make error view that i return in my try catch
its work well when my method retrun ModelAnd View but how can i return my view when my method have a String return?

like this

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/librairie/supprimerLivre/{isbn}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String supprimerLivre(@PathVariable("isbn") String isbn, HttpServletRequest request){
    try{
      gestPanier = new GestPanier(request);
      //rechercher le livre qui correspond a l'isbn passer en parametre
    LivreAchete livre = gestPanier.getListe().stream().filter(c -> c.getIsbn().equals(isbn)).findFirst().get();

    //supprimer le livre
    gestPanier.supprimer(livre);
    return "redirect:/librairie/afficherPanier";  
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        return ModelAndView  return new ModelAndView("Error", "model",new ErrorviewModel("/librairie/paiement", ex.getMessage(), ex));
    }
}
```

i cant return ModelAndView because my method have a String return but how i can redirect to my view?

Comment: What do you mean with "redirect"?

Comment: Also, is ModelAndView a "box" with your error? If it is, you can simply replace it by using javax.swing.JOptionPane

Comment: i mean something like this return "redirect:/librairie/afficherPanier"; what you mean with box?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by using throws instead of try-catch.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/librairie/supprimerLivre/{isbn}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String supprimerLivre(@PathVariable("isbn") String isbn, HttpServletRequest request) 
throws Exception{
    gestPanier = new GestPanier(request);
    LivreAchete livre = gestPanier.getListe().stream().filter(c -> c.getIsbn().equals(isbn)).findFirst().get();

    gestPanier.supprimer(livre);
    return "redirect:/librairie/afficherPanier";
}
```

Then handle the exception where you call the method.

```
try{
    supprimerLivre(isbn, request); //That's where you call the method
} catch (Exception e) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("Error", "model",new ErrorviewModel("/librairie/paiement", ex.getMessage(), ex));
}
```

Comment: I dont understand how i can return ModelAndView??? my method return string ... public String supprimerLivre(@PathVariable("isbn") String isbn, HttpServletRequest request) 
throws Exception{

Comment: You can't return ModelAndView. You are using String as return value. Here you are simply handling exception in a different place. If you want to return ModelAndView you can replace String to Object, but you can easily make mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (it's one of the Spring way of controller based exception handling):

```
    // Name of the function is not important (just an example)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class) // Or handle some custom exception of yours
    public ModelAndView supprimerLivreHandler(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex) {
        return new ModelAndView("Error", "model",new ErrorviewModel("/librairie/paiement", ex.getMessage(), ex));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/librairie/supprimerLivre/{isbn}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String supprimerLivre(@PathVariable("isbn") String isbn, HttpServletRequest request){
        try{
            gestPanier = new GestPanier(request);
            //rechercher le livre qui correspond a l'isbn passer en parametre
            LivreAchete livre = gestPanier.getListe().stream().filter(c -> c.getIsbn().equals(isbn)).findFirst().get();

            //supprimer le livre
            gestPanier.supprimer(livre);
            return "redirect:/librairie/afficherPanier";
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            // When this Exception is thrown, the supprimerLivreHandler function will be called
            throw new RuntimeException(); // Or throw some custom exception of yours
        }
    }
```

If you wish to read more about Spring MVC exception handling, please refer to [this  website](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) (my example is based on one of the methods described on that website).